# HTMLAudioElement Audio Not Playing on iOS (Ionic App)

Tags: ios, html, ionic-framework, xcode8

I am using Xcode 8 and Ionic. I can get audio to play on Android but not iOS. The log from Xcode says this:

```
2016-07-13 18:19:44.802014 SpotShuffle[830:104683] [] <<<< FIGSANDBOX >>>> Path </private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EC634407-1752-4EE2-814E-B88353EA36B0/tmp/MediaCache> could not be converted by realpath() (requires all elements of path are present)

2016-07-13 18:19:44.803145 SpotShuffle[830:104683] [] __InternalSandboxRegisterURL_block_invoke signalled err=-12780 (kFigBaseObjectError_ParamErr) (Could not obtain realpath for specified URL) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMediaFramework/EmbeddedCoreMedia-1847.11.1/Prototypes/Player/ClientServer/FigSandboxSupport.c line 590
```

Do you have any advice?

Comment: did you solve the problem? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a similar error trying to play a video in iOS 10 beta 2.

"Could not obtain realpath for specified URL"

```
ObtainAndRegisterSandboxExtensionForPath signalled err=-12780 (kFigBaseObjectError_ParamErr) (Could not obtain realpath for specified URL) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMediaFramework/EmbeddedCoreMedia-1873/Prototypes/Player/ClientServer/FigSandboxSupport.c line 486
```

My guess is that somewhere in the file is a URL starting with "//:" instead of "http//:". Web browsers will pickup the right URL protocol from the pages URL. In Ionic and Cordova the page protocol is "file://", which might be breaking the realpath library.

Answer (score 0):

try to covert your audio file to base64

```
mySound = new Audio("data:audio/mp3;base64,//uQBAAAAAA....    ..qq");  
collectSound.play();
```

it may work. however it may open system player as well. need to find a way to keep the context of you app